# IOS - UITableViewCell overlapping UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Im using AutoLayout in my cells but, when the cell has large text inside the cell and the cell expands the cell seems to overlap the cell below. Image shows how this is overlapping the cells:

[image]

UITableViewCell:

```
        #import "PostTableViewCell.h"

        @implementation PostTableViewCell

        @synthesize main;
        @synthesize top;
        @synthesize center;
        @synthesize centerLeft;
        @synthesize centerRight;
        @synthesize bottom;
        @synthesize labelMessage;
        @synthesize labelCat;
        @synthesize labelSubCat;
        @synthesize labelCountry;
        @synthesize labelUser;
        @synthesize labelDate;
        @synthesize imageviewThreadImage;
        @synthesize split;


        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self) {
            [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

            main = [UIView new];
            [self.contentView addSubview:main];
            main.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [main sizeToFit];
            main.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            top = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:top];
            top.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [top sizeToFit];
            top.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            labelUser = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelUser];
            labelUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelUser sizeToFit];
            [labelUser setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
            labelUser.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelDate = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelDate];
            labelDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelDate sizeToFit];
            [labelDate setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
            labelDate.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            center = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:center];
            center.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [center sizeToFit];
            center.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            imageviewThreadImage = [UIImageView new];
            [center addSubview:imageviewThreadImage];
            imageviewThreadImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            imageviewThreadImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            [imageviewThreadImage sizeToFit];

            labelMessage = [UILabel new];
            [center addSubview:labelMessage];
            labelMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelMessage sizeToFit];
            [labelMessage setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth - 10 - 36;
            labelMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
            labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            //labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            //labelMessage.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            bottom = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:bottom];
            bottom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [bottom sizeToFit];

            labelCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCat];
            labelCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCat sizeToFit];
            [labelCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
            labelCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            labelCat.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelCat.numberOfLines = 0;

            labelSubCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelSubCat];
            labelSubCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelSubCat sizeToFit];
            [labelSubCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
            labelSubCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelCountry = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCountry];
            labelCountry.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCountry sizeToFit];
            [labelCountry setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
            labelCountry.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            split = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:split];
            split.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [split sizeToFit];
            split.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


            }

            return self;
        }

        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            [super layoutSubviews];
            // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
            // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
            [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
            // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
            self.labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.labelMessage.frame);
        }

        - (void)updateConstraints {
            [super updateConstraints];

            if (self.didSetupConstraints) return;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"main":main};
            NSArray *constraint_H37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];

            NSArray *constraint_V37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H37];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_V37];

            //NSString *text = labelMessage.text;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary3 = @{@"top":top,@"center":center,@"bottom":bottom,@"split":split};
            NSArray *constraint_H3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[top]-5-[center(>=40)]-5-[bottom]-10-[split(1)]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33cvcv4545fdd = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[split]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[top]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H333 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[center]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H3335657 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottom]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4 = @{@"labelUser":labelUser,@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelUser]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary45 = @{@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4555 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelDate]|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary45];

            NSArray *constraint_H44 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelUser]-20-[labelDate]-5-|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary48 = @{@"labelMessage":labelMessage,@"imageviewThreadImage":imageviewThreadImage};



            NSArray *constraint_H48 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelMessage]-5-|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSArray *constraint_H48342 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary48];



            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary48];

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-46-[labelMessage(%f)]-10-|",screenWidth - 51]
                                                   options:0
                                                   metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary48];




            /**NSArray *constraint_H448 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelMessage]-5-|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
             views:viewsDictionary48];**/

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary488 = @{@"labelCat":labelCat,@"labelCountry":labelCountry,@"labelSubCat":labelSubCat};
            NSArray *constraint_H488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCat]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCountry]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelSubCat]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary488];

            NSArray *constraint_H4488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelCat]-10-[labelSubCat]-10-[labelCountry]"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary488];



            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H333];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H44];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48];
            //[self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4555];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3335657];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48342];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfg];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33cvcv4545fdd];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454];



            self.didSetupConstraints = YES;

        }



        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            // Initialization code
        }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
            [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @end
```

How my cells are reused:

CellForRowIndexPath -

```
if(tableView == tableViewPost){


    Post *t = (Post*)[tmpArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem46";

            PostTableViewCell *cell = (PostTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            //cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
            //cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }


            cell.labelMessage.text = t.message;
            cell.labelCat.text = t.cat;
            cell.labelSubCat.text = t.subcat;
            cell.labelCountry.text = t.country;
            cell.labelUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.user];
            cell.labelDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.date];


            [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
            return cell;

        }
```

HeightForRowIndexPath -

```
if(tableView == tableViewPost){



        Post *t = (Post*)[tmpArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            PostTableViewCell *cell = (PostTableViewCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];


            CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
            //CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];



            return height;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using iOS 8 or greater you can try

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
```

Comment: That seems to have worked when the cells first load but, now when i scroll the overlapping happens again

Comment: you can improve the estimatedRowHeight with the delegate method estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath similar to heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: be sure to fill the labels in your estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath with the correct content. Because you are not doing this in your code above! And if this still not working you can be sure that something is wrong with your constraints